# How make a portable Intellij IDEA Ultimate be recognised by Flutter Doctor?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, intellij-idea

I used to have a portable development environment. Where I have a IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate installed in a External SSD Drive (https://portapps.io/app/intellij-idea-ultimate-portable/). I'm starting to code in Flutter and I having this issue.

When I run "flutter doctor -v", the flutter doesn't recognise the portable version (and I understand, because is not in the default directory).

The question is, how to make flutter doctor recognise this external installation (from zip file)?

I have everything configured correctly, here is my current "flutter doctor -v" output:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.900], locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 1.17.5 at Z:\SDK\Flutter
    • Framework revision 8af6b2f038 (10 days ago), 2020-06-30 12:53:55 -0700
    • Engine revision ee76268252
    • Dart version 2.8.4


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
    • Android SDK at Z:\SDK\Android
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.1
    • ANDROID_HOME = Z:\SDK\Android
    • Java binary at: Z:\SDK\OpenJDK\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_252-b09)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: Have you installed the Flutter and Dart plugins inside your IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Yes @hisam. The plugins are ok.

Comment: Please try submitting an issue to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/; looks as if it only checks some hardcoded locations when searching for plugins.

Comment: @lena I made the submission. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/61304

Answer (score 0):

You're free to use IntelliJ (or any other IDE) for flutter development, but it won't satisfy the checks made by flutter doctor.  It's looking specifically for Android Studio.  If you want to use IntelliJ then you have to live with flutter doctor's warnings about Android Studio not being installed.

If you want to use a portable version of Android Studio then use the command

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir "Z:\MyPortableApps\AndroidStudio"
```

with the path to your portable application.

If you want to see what has been configured then just use `flutter config` without any parameters.  The output starts with a load of usage text but at the end you'll find a section with the heading **Settings:** listing anything that has been set.  A new install won't have anything set and will just use defaults.

To later unset a value use a quoted empty string "" in the same command.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but the problem is that this command doesn't work.

Comment: Can you explain how it doesn't work?  Is there an error message?  Have you switched to Android Studio or are you still trying to use IntelliJ?

Comment: I made the download of the android studii from the same website, type the command in the terminal with the complete path and just don't recognize.